Can i create a website for a signed in or authorize user to reset their passwords from azure by themselves as a cloud application adminstrator?
I am trying to create a self service password reset website  to let users reset their password by themselves. I have been granted the cloud application administrator role with these permissions in Azure: Directory.AccessAsUser.All Directory.ReadWrite.All email Mail.Send openid profile User.Read User.ReadWrite.All UserAuthenticationMethod.ReadWrite.All. I am able to authenticate the user and get the token however while i try to reset their password using the token. I am getting error. Do i need some other permissions or other role like user administrator role or password administrator role for this?
I am still getting this error as an User Adminstrator Role
  error: {
    code: 'Authorization_RequestDenied',
    message: 'Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.',
    innerError: {
      date: '2024-10-10T07:09:04',
      'request-id': '7d1376c0-092b-4707-a4e8-cb480d15ae67',
      'client-request-id': '7d1376c0-092b-4707-a4e8-cb480d15ae67'
    }

What could be the issue now
[Error][2]
Here is my password reset code
// Reset Password for authenticated users
const resetPassword = async (req, res) => {
  const { password, accessToken, userId } = req.body;
  console.log(
    "This is the user ID: " +
      userId +
      "New Password: " +
      password +
      "Token" +
      accessToken
  );

  // const decodedToken = jwt.decode(accessToken);
  // console.log("thisis the decoded token", decodedToken);
  try {
    const graphClientResponse = await axios.patch(
      `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${userId}`,
      {
        passwordProfile: {
          password: password,
          forceChangePasswordNextSignIn: false,
        },
      },
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    );
    console.log(
      "Password reset for user with token:",
      graphClientResponse.data
    );
    res.status(200).json({ message: "Password reset successful!" });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error resetting password:", err);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Error resetting password." });
  }
};

Token
const getToken = async (req, res) => {
  const { code } = req.body;

  const tokenRequest = {
    client_id: msalConfig.auth.clientId,
    client_secret: msalConfig.auth.clientSecret,
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
    code: code,
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000",
    scope:
      "openid profile email offline_access https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
  };

  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token`,
      qs.stringify(tokenRequest),
      { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" } }
    );
    const accessToken = response.data.access_token;

    const graphResponse = await axios.get(
      "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me",
      {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` },
      }
    );

    const username = graphResponse.data.displayName;
    const id = graphResponse.data.id;
    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      accessToken: accessToken,
      username: username,
      id: id,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error exchanging authorization code:", err);
    res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      message: "Error exchanging authorization code for token",
    });
  }
};


I am using oauth2 authentication flow

Is it client credentials flow or any delegated flow like authorization code or interactive?

Authorization code flow

To update password profile of users, you need to assign at least User Administrator role to signed-in user.

Could you try adding that role to signed-in user and confirm whether it worked or not?

Could you tell me as a User Administrator would i be able to change the password of any other users on their behalf? I only want a signed in user or an authorized user to be able to change their password themselves.

Yes, with User Administrator access you can change password of any other users. If you only want a signed in user or an authorized user to be able to change their password themselves, switch to this API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-changepassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

This would need a user to know their current password. What if the user does not remember their password they can still be authorized but the problem is they won't be able to change their password unless they know remember their old password

That's the only possible way if you prefer not to assign User Administrator role to user.

Please avoid lengthy discussion in comments - that's not what comments are for. Please update the question, rather than going back-n-forth.

Hi @DipRaj Any update?

As mentioned in this MS Document,

Along with Directory.AccessAsUser.All  delegated permission, the calling user must have a higher privileged administrator role to update sensitive user properties like passwordProfile for users with  administrator roles

I registered one application and granted same API permissions of Delegated type like this:

Initially, I too got same error when I tried to sign in with user having User Administrator role to reset password:

Using  User Administrator role, you can only reset passwords of non-admin users and a limited set of admin roles as defined in Who can reset passwords.
For resetting admin user passwords, the calling user need to have higher privileged administrator roles like Privileged Authentication Administrator or Global Administrator.
In my case, I assigned Privileged Authentication Administrator role to calling user like this:

When I ran the code again after assigning above role, it worked and password reset is successful:
App.js:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { MsalProvider, useMsal } from '@azure/msal-react';
import { PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';

const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID,
    authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.REACT_APP_TENANT_ID}`,
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000',
  },
};

const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

const App = () => {
  const { instance } = useMsal();
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const handleLogin = async () => {
    try {
      const loginResponse = await instance.loginPopup({
        scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email', 'User.ReadWrite.All', 'Directory.AccessAsUser.All'],
      });
      console.log('Login response:', loginResponse);
      alert(`Logged in as: ${loginResponse.account.username}`);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Login error:', err);
      alert('Login failed. Please try again.');
    }
  };

  const handlePasswordReset = async () => {
    if (!userId || !password) {
      console.error("User ID and Password must not be empty.");
      alert("Please enter both User ID and New Password.");
      return;
    }

    try {
      const tokenResponse = await instance.acquireTokenSilent({
        scopes: ['User.ReadWrite.All', 'Directory.AccessAsUser.All'],
        account: instance.getAllAccounts()[0],
      });

      const graphClientResponse = await axios.patch(
        `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${userId}`,
        {
          passwordProfile: {
            password: password,
            forceChangePasswordNextSignIn: false,
          },
        },
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${tokenResponse.accessToken}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        }
      );

      console.log('Password reset successful:', graphClientResponse.data);
      alert("Password reset successful!");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error resetting password:', err);
      if (err.response) {
        // Log status code and error message
        const statusCode = err.response.status;
        const errorMessage = err.response.data.error.message;
        console.error(`Error Status Code: ${statusCode}`);
        alert(`Error resetting password: ${statusCode} - ${errorMessage}`);
      } else {
        alert("Error resetting password. Please try again.");
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Password Reset</h1>
      <button onClick={handleLogin}>Login</button>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="User ID (email or object ID)"
        value={userId}
        onChange={(e) => setUserId(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        type="password"
        placeholder="New Password"
        value={password}
        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={handlePasswordReset}>Reset Password</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const Root = () => (
  <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
    <App />
  </MsalProvider>
);

export default Root;

App.css:
.App {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 90%;
}

button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}

Output:

